# Could I use the SQL statement, SELECT * from sysobjects, with C# MySQL Connector - .NET?

Tags: mysql-5.6, c#

I would like to port a SQL statement, `SELECT * from sysobjects`,  written for Microsoft SQL Server  to MySQL version 5.6.

Could I use the SQL statement,  `SELECT * from sysobjects`, with C# MySQL Connector - .NET or do I have to modify it?

I realize that I can get such a C# MySQL Connector - .NET to compile but that is no guarantee it can be executed correctly?

If I have to modify the SQL statement, how might I do it?
  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA;